# Calculating total sales with multiple criterias across two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently working with **Table 1** and trying to calculate the total sales **[Column C]** of products with the same **ID** and matching stock units and sales units in **Table 2**. I've attempted to use the SUMIFS formula like so:

```
=SUMIFS(Table2!E:E, Table2!A:A, Table1!A1, Table2!C:C, Table2!D:D)
```

However, it doesn't seem to be giving me the desired result. Could someone please lend a hand and assist me with this? I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Table 1 (Desired Results):

[image: Table 1]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then `SUMIFS()` isn't the right function that will work for the desired output, instead use the following as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd> of `Sheet Named Table1` and fill down:

```
=LET(
     _extract, FILTER(Table2!C$2:E$19,(Table2!A$2:A$19=Table1!A2)*(Table1!B2=Table2!B$2:B$19),""),
     SUM(--(INDEX(_extract,,1)=INDEX(_extract,,2))*TAKE(_extract,,-1)))
```

---

- Using `FILTER()` function extract the range of data with headers as `Stock Unit`, `Sales Unit` and `Sales` based on `ID` and `Name`
- Next, using `SUM()` function doing a boolean operation to compare between the `Sales Unit` and `Stock Unit` arrays extracted from above to do a sum of the products of corresponding arrays.

---

Also If you are using `MS365` then you can spill the whole output with one single formula, therefore no need to fill down here:

```
=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,y,
  LET(z, FILTER(Table2!C:E,(Table2!A:A=x)*(Table2!B:B=y),""), 
  SUM(--(INDEX(z,,1)=INDEX(z,,2))*TAKE(z,,-1)))))
```

---

- Using `MAP()` function to iterate each cell values to perform a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations.
- Within the `LAMBDA()` using a `LET()` to pass a `FILTER()` function to extract the three desired columns based on `ID` and `Name`
- Next, doing a sum of the products of corresponding arrays here, comparing with `Stock Unit` --> `INDEX(z,,1)` with `Sales Unit` --> `INDEX(z,,2)` which returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` and then multiplying the same with `Sales` to get the desired output after summing.

---

One easy way could be using `SUMIFS()` with the `Sales Unit` Column taken as `Criteria Range` and `Stock Units` Column as `Criteria` however, it depends on your preference:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    SUMIFS(
        Table2!E:E,
        Table2!A:A, Table1!A2,
        Table2!B:B, Table1!B2,
        Table2!D:D, UNIQUE(
            Table2!C:C
        )
    )
)
```

---

One more alternative way but this is recommended, it will slow down the excel efficiency.

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table2!E:E,(IFNA(XMATCH(Table2!D:D,UNIQUE(Table2!C:C)),0))*(A2=Table2!A:A)*(Table2!B:B=Table1!B2),0))
```

---

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! Since I'm dealing with a large amount of data, Excel tends to take a bit of time to perform calculations. Do you happen to know how I could implement this formula in Power Query?

Comment: I will try to update when I can !

Comment: @newt335 here is a link with `Power Query` solution which doesnt require the second table: **[Download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckzZeCBBEb3iHHt9u?e=n2RZAz)** and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh Bhattacharya. Appreciate your help!